# acts-as-taggable-on gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I know `ActsAsTaggableOn.remove_unused_tags = true` is for the lasted version. In 2.2 I used `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.remove_unused = true`. How about `ActsAsTaggableOn.force_lowercase = true`? What is the equivalent for 2.2 version?

Comment: surf to github..https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/tree/v2.2.0 - and there search for your method..

Comment: Like @Mattherick told. You can take a look to the compare view: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/compare/v2.2.0...master@%7B1day%7D